# How do i add additional rows in M QUERY

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerquery, powerbi-desktop, m

I want to add more rows using the Query editor (Power query/ M Query) in only the Start Date and End Date column:

```
+----------+------------------+--------------+-----------+-------------+------------+
| Employee |  Booking Type    |     Jobs     | WorkLoad% | Start Date  |  End date  |
+----------+------------------+--------------+-----------+-------------+------------+
| John     | Chargeable       | CNS          |        20 | 04/02/2020  | 31/03/2020 |
| John     | Chargeable       | CNS          |        20 | 04/03/2020  | 27/04/2020 |
| Bernard  | Vacation/Holiday | SN           |       100 | 30/04/2020  | 11/05/2020 |
| Bernard  | Vacation/Holiday | Annual leave |       100 | 23/01/2020  | 24/02/2020 |
| Bernard  | Chargeable       | Tech PLC     |        50 | 29/02/2020  | 30/03/2020 |
+----------+------------------+--------------+-----------+-------------+------------+
```

I want to find the `MIN(Start Date)` and `MAX(End Date)` and then append the range of start to end dates to this table only in the Start Date and End Date column in the Query Editor (Power Query/ M Query). Preferrable if I can create another table2 duplicating the original table and append these rows.
For example:

```
+----------+------------------+--------------+-----------+-------------+------------+
| Employee |  Booking Type    |     Jobs     | WorkLoad% | Start Date  |  End date  |
+----------+------------------+--------------+-----------+-------------+------------+
| John     | Chargeable       | CNS          |        20 | 04/02/2020  | 31/03/2020 |
| John     | Chargeable       | CNS          |        20 | 04/03/2020  | 27/04/2020 |
| Bernard  | Vacation/Holiday | SN           |       100 | 30/04/2020  | 11/05/2020 |
| Bernard  | Vacation/Holiday | Annual leave |       100 | 23/01/2020  | 24/02/2020 |
| Bernard  | Chargeable       | Tech PLC     |        50 | 29/02/2020  | 30/03/2020 |
|          |                  |              |           | 23/01/2020  | 23/01/2020 |
|          |                  |              |           | 24/01/2020  | 24/01/2020 |
|          |                  |              |           | 25/01/2020  | 25/01/2020 |
|          |                  |              |           | 26/01/2020  | 26/01/2020 |
|          |                  |              |           | 27/01/2020  | 27/01/2020 |
|          |                  |              |           | 28/01/2020  | 28/01/2020 |
|          |                  |              |           | 29/01/2020  | 29/01/2020 |
|          |                  |              |           | 30/01/2020  | 30/01/2020 |
|          |                  |              |           | 31/01/2020  | 31/01/2020 |
|          |                  |              |           | ...         | ...        |
|          |                  |              |           | 11/05/2020  | 11/05/2020 |
+----------+------------------+--------------+-----------+-------------+------------+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`List.Dates` function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerquery-m/list-dates) is pretty useful here.

Generate the dates in your range, duplicate that to two columns and then append.

```
let
    StartDate = List.Min(StartTable[Start Date]),
    EndDate = List.Max(StartTable[End Date]),
    DateList = List.Dates(StartDate, Duration.Days(EndDate - StartDate), #duration(1,0,0,0)),
    DateCols = Table.FromColumns({DateList, DateList}, {"Start Date", "End Date"}),
    AppendDates = Table.Combine({StartTable, DateCols})
in
    AppendDates
```